# Navigate properly between tab in a WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, tabs

I'm doing a WPF application with the M-V-VM patern (i'm using galasoft if it's relevant), but I have issues when I navigate through a tabcontrol.
I'm adding tabs on the run. All the binding seems to goes well : inside the tab or in the header of the tab.
I've bind my tabcontrol to a observable list. Through an interface I'm adding several types of viewmodel to this list and the binding seems correct.
My XAML code looks like this :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
            <TechnicalControls:ItemTab />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainTab" Grid.Column="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TabViewModels}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"

            ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource LastItemStyleSelector}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}"
            >

        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:JobViewModel}" x:Shared="False" >
                <FunctionnalControls:Job />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ExcelJobViewModel}" x:Shared="False">
                <FunctionnalControls:ExcelJob />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:MonitoringViewModel}" x:Shared="False">
                <FunctionnalControls:Monitoring />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ErrorViewModel}" x:Shared="False">
                <FunctionnalControls:Error />
            </DataTemplate>                

        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

For example if I go from a ExcelJob to another ExcelJob usercontrol, the new usercontrol is not load properly but it changes then it works, for exemple, I can go to a ExcelJob to another ExcelJob if only I go through the monitoring.

I've already look to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601826/multiple-usercontrol-instances-in-tabcontrol) but it didn't work for me.
I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538364/wpf-custom-textbox-takes-two-tabs-to-get-to-text) : it says that we should not used inputs because you can focus them. I've tried to set the IsEnabled property on the users controls to false. I did it when tabs were changing. It didn't work...

The only solution that I can see is to go through another a new usercontrol with no other purpose to be used every time a tab is changed but this is ugly, and I'm pretty sure, Microsoft thought about this and came up with a better solution.

If necessary I can put the code of the view model.

EDIT : Just to clarify, when I click on other tab with the same control, instead of showing me the new usercontrol, it shows me the previous one. In order to see the new one, I have to change to another tab with another usercontrol then come back on the one I want to see.
I've look through debug and the when I click on the other tab It doesn't call the viewmodel

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.ExcelJob"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             DataContext="{Binding Main.ExcelJobVM, Source={StaticResource Locator }}">
    <Grid >
        <Label>Futur Excel Job</Label>
        <TextBox Width="200" Height="60" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So Main returns the Mainviewmodel and Main.ExcelJobVM returns the good viewmodel of the usercontrol. the returned isntance is based on selected Index.
The only thing I need is to force the redrawing of the usercontrol or recall the method to update the datacontext, by loading the good viewmodel. I tried, I've failed so far. I'm not sure of what I'm doing because I want to use the event SelectionChanged of the tabcontrol but it would be in the code behind, and I don't know if it would still respect the MVVM pattern.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you have both the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` properties bound. Those both actually accomplish the same thing (set the selected item), and I've seen it cause problems when you set both properties at once. Just set one or the other.

Comment: Also when you say "the new usercontrol is not load properly", what do you mean by that? If you change from one `ExcelJob` to another `ExcelJob`, WPF might not bother re-drawing the template, however it should change the `DataContext` behind the template, so anything bound should change.

Comment: @rachel Thanks I will change remove one of the selected property. And to explain it better, If I change from one ExcelJob to another, the new one is not loaded properly, the previous one is still displayed instead of the new one.

Comment: That is how WPF templates work. If two items are getting drawn using the exact same template, WPF doesn't bother to generate a new template and only changes the `DataContext` behind it. You could try [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3627308/302677) to overwrite a tab control so instead of unloading/reloading each tab when you change, it uses an existing `ContentPresenter` for the tab, but I'm not positive if that would work.

Comment: The data context is not updated since the new context is from another ExcelJob viewmodel that is never load.
Thanks I will try that.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like having both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` is causing problems. Do you have the same problem when you only have one of those properties set?

Comment: @rachel No it is not working because since the usercontrol is not redrawing so the other viewmodel is not called and the datacontext is not updated. Is it possible to redefined the datacontext in a trigger (like the one triggered by the changement of tab) ?
  I will implement the solution you first gave me but I'm not sure how to do it because you redefined the tabcontrol class, How am I suppose to use it in the XAML ? (Sorry but I'm new to WPF & MVVM)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wait... is the `DataContext` you said is "not working" created by your `UserControl`? Your `View` layer redrawing should have no affect whatsoever on your `ViewModel` layer. Can you update your question with a simplified example of how your UserControl's look, and what `DataContext` is incorrect?

Comment: @Rachel I've updated my question, sorry for my English I'm far for being a native speaker.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the `DataContext` into your `UserControl` instead of letting it get passed from the `TabViewModels`? That's probably the problem there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `DataContext` hardcoded in your `UserControl`, and your `UserControl` is a Template.

When you switch to a tab that uses the same `Template`, WPF doesn't bother to redraw the template and only changes the `DataContext` behind the template. But in your case, you have the `DataContext` hardcoded in the `UserControl`, so it's not using the existing data context from the TabItem.

The best solution would be to remove the `DataContext` binding from your UserControl, and let it be inherited from the `TabItem` when the selected item changes.

For example:

WPF says

> User has selected `ExcelJobA` for display. Because of the DataTemplate, let me draw it using an ExcelJob UserControl

```
<TabItem>
    <ContentPresenter DataContext="ExcelJobA">
        <local:ExcelJob DataContext="{Binding Main.ExcelJobVM, Source={StaticResource Locator }}" />
    </ContentPresenter>
</TabItem>
```

So an `ExcelJob` UserControl gets created, and by default the DataContext of `ExcelJobA` would be inherited by the UserControl.

When the user changes the selected tab to `ExcelJobB`, WPF goes

> Hey, the user has changed to `ExcelJobB`. Because of the DataTemplate, let me draw it using an `ExcelJob` UserControl, BUT WAIT! I'm already displaying an `ExcelJob` UserControl, so let me just change the DataContext behind that to `ExcelJobB`

```
<TabItem>
    <ContentPresenter DataContext="ExcelJobB">
        <local:ExcelJob DataContext="{Binding Main.ExcelJobVM, Source={StaticResource Locator }}" />
    </ContentPresenter>
</TabItem>
```

So the actual displayed `ExcelJob` UserControl does not get recreated or redrawn, but only the `DataContext` behind it changes.

**HOWEVER**, because you have hard-coded the `DataContext` inside your `UserControl`, the actual data context obtained from the selected item doesn't ever get used, because a `DataContext` specified from inside a `<Tag>` always takes precedence over a `DataContext` that would be inherited from further up the visual tree.

You need to remove the `DataContext` binding from inside your `UserControl`, and let it get passed in normally from your TabControl's `SelectedItem`, and it will work fine.

```
<TabItem>
    <ContentPresenter DataContext="ExcelJobA">
        <local:ExcelJob /> <!-- DataContext inherited from the ContentPresenter -->
    </ContentPresenter> 
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time, I will implement this tuesday when I will be back to work !  
Thanks for your time, you gave me a better understanding of WPF !